# Saving a List of Objects in Windows Phone 7 XNA

Tags: xna, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer, windows-phone, isolatedstoragefile

i need to save a List of Objects, The Objects are created from a class i made. what should i do?

i tried the XmlSerializer, and i added the [XmlElement] to the fields i need to be serialized. but it kept giving me "There is an Error in XML Document". 
I tried also the DataContractSerializer, and i used the [DataContract] and [DataMember] but it wont save my objects.

both storage classes work for basic elements (int,bool .. etc) but not my objects.

heres my code for saving:

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile saveGameFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream SaveGameStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("GemsCollector1.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, saveGameFile))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Card>));
            serializer.Serialize(SaveGameStream, Cards);
        }
```

and this one for loading:

```
        using (IsolatedStorageFile saveGameFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream saveGameStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("GemsCollector1.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, saveGameFile))
        {
            if (saveGameStream.Length > 0)
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Card>));
                Cards = (List<Card>)serializer.Deserialize(saveGameStream);
            }

        }
```

my Card Class:

```
public class Card
{
    [XmlElement]
    public CardType CardType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public CardColor CardColor { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int Value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public PlayerPosition playerPosition { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public CardStatus Status { get; set; }
    public Rectangle BoundingBox
    {
        get
        {
            int width = (playerPosition == PlayerPosition.Left || playerPosition == PlayerPosition.Right) ? 150 : 100;
            int height = (playerPosition == PlayerPosition.Left || playerPosition == PlayerPosition.Right) ? 100 : 150;
            return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, width, height); ;
        }
    }
    [XmlElement]
    public bool isUsed;
    public Vector2 endPosition = new Vector2(235,200);
    public Rectangle ThrowArea = new Rectangle(235, 200, 350, 120);
    [XmlElement]
    public string cardTextureName;
    private string back = "back";
    private static bool ReserveDrag;
    [XmlElement]
    private Vector2 touchFromCenter;
    [XmlElement]
    private int touchId;


    public Card()
    {
    }
}
```

can anybody please tell me how we save List of userdefined objects in XNA?

Comment: Are you attempting to save it to the Phone's IsolatedStorage? And if so, you should perhaps post your serialization code.

Comment: yes, to the IsolatedStroage, and i just added my code

Comment: Right, so the error is related to the "Card" object you're trying to serialize. I think we can safely assume that you haven't made the class property serializable. So you'll have to post the Card class here as well.

Comment: okay i just added my class, i removed the methods because they are so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to serialize private properties. That's not supported on Windows Phone 7. Which could easily be cause for the error.

Also, you have to ensure that all of the types you used for properties, is also serializeable, and that all types have a empty constructor.

Comment: Enumerables are serializeable by default. Also you don't have to explicit mark members as serializeable, if the class is.